# Remove folder at shutdown or reboot

Tags: shell-script, sysvinit, yocto

I have a folder /mnt/automounts which is used to automount usb drives in (which is working.). There is one scenario that still causes an issue. When a usb drive is plugged in, then the system is shut down and afterwards I unplug the usb drive. When i start up the system again the specific folder of the mount is still present in mnt/automounts.

For this reason I would like to start a script at shutdown (and reboot) that removes the automounts folder. to do this I've created a shell script called clearmnt.sh and put it in the /etc/init.d folder>

clearmnt.sh looks like this:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> ### BEGIN INIT INFO
>
> # Provides:          clearmnt
>
> # Required-Start:
>
> # Required-Stop:
>
> # Should-Stop:
> # Default-Start:    0 6
>
> # Default-Stop:
> # Short-Description: removes directories of automounted folders in /mnt
>
> ### END INIT INFO
>
> rm -rf /mnt/automounts

Then I've created soft links in rc0.d and rc6.d (shutdown and reboot):

> sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/clearmnt.sh /etc/rc0.d/clear_mnt
>
> sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/clearmnt.sh /etc/rc6.d/clear_mnt

And then I made clearmnt.sh executable:

> sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/clearmnt.sh

Then I did a reboot to see if it works. It did not, the /mnt/automounts folder is still there after reboot.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or what step I am missing?
This is all done on a yocto build.

Comment: You want to `rm -rf /mnt/automounts/*`

Comment: That did also not remove the automounts folder here. Really looks like the script does not get executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you really want this? Imagine the situation you described. You have an USB storage plugged in, and you shut down your system. Your shutdown script executes `rm -rf /mnt/automounts` (or `rm -rf /mnt/automounts/*`, doesn't matter).

Later you reboot and find out that all the files on your USB storage are **deleted**.

So what you should do is delete the directories after the reboot, when the USB storage is not mounted.

Or even easier, create a small `tmpfs` that is kept in RAM, you don't need much space because it contains just the directories for the mount points, and it is automatically empty when you boot.

Comment: You are right, I like the the small tmpfs kept in RAM idea. Thanx